# Integrating deterministic function with respect to Brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

I have looked everywhere for a satisfactory answer to this, including Shreve's textbooks, but I can't find one.

If I want to integrate a some deterministic function f(t) with respect to brownian motion, i.e. 
$$
  \int_0^tf(s)\mathrm dB_s
$$
what is the solution?

I understand how to decompose this into a Ito integral. I also understand that the integral must have a normal distribution, and it is relatively simple to calculate the mean $= 0$ and the variance:
$$
  \mathsf{Var} =   \mathsf E  (\int_0^tf(s)\mathrm dB_s)^2 = \mathsf E\int_0^tf^2(s)\mathrm ds.
$$
so does this mean I can write the answer as 
$$
    \int_0^tf(s)\mathrm dB_s =  \sqrt{\mathsf{Var}}B_t?
$$
Because this would have a normal distribution with the correct mean and variance. It also makes sense to write the solution as N(0, variance).

Is either of these a correct solution to the integral of a generic deterministic function with respect to B.M.?

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Paul

Comment: sorry I couldn't figure out how to format the equations correctly. I am working on tediting them; I just wanted to get this question out there ASAP.

Comment: I flagged that this question better fits MSE. Moreover, indeed for any *fixed* time $t$ the random variable 
$$
  I_t := \int_0^t f_s\mathrm dB_s
$$
is normally distributed. However, if we consider $(I_t)_{t\geq 0}$ as a process, then there is a certain dependence between random variables $I_{t'}$ and $I_{t''}$ for $t'\neq t''$, which I guess is uniquely determined by covariance (in case $(I_{t'},I_{t''})$ are jointly Gaussian). Note that you can't "decompose" it into the Riemann integral, but you can apply Euler-Maryama scheme to simulate the result.

Comment: Ilya, thanks for your prompt response. I am a little confused at your notation t'/=t''. Could you maybe explain what this would mean if f(t)=exp(t), so that f=f'=f''?

Comment: That means $t'$ not equal to $t''$.

Comment: so you mean t'=dt/dB?...Apologies because I have never seen this notation before. could you please point me towards an equation that shows this dependence?

Comment: With $t'$ I didn't mean a derivative, just to distinguish between two time moment. Think of $t_1$ and $t_2$ on their place. What I mean is that $I_{t_1}$ and $I_{t_2}$ in general may have different dependence structure, then in process $\sqrt{\mathsf{Var}_{t_1}} B_{t_1}$ and $\sqrt{\mathsf{Var}_{t_2}} B_{t_2}$. An important thing (sometimes missed) is: stochastic process is about *joint* distributions of $I_{t_1},I_{t_2},\dots,I_{t_n}$ altogether. It is not enough just to specify distributions of $I_{t_k}$ separately from each other, so $\mathcal N(0,Var)$ is *not* a unique stochastic process

Comment: ok, that makes more sense. But if I_t_1 (thinking of t_1 as a constant) is always normally distributed, doesn't this imply that each increment I_t_2-I_t_1 is also normally distributed? Although I see now that this does not necessarily imply the independence of increments. So you are saying the integral is a Gaussian process, but not neccesarily scaled B.M.?

Comment: Actually I just checked with f=exp(t), and it seems that the covariance of I_t_1 and I_t_2 is the same as the variance of I_min(t_1,t_2). Doesn't this imply independent increments and that the integral in this case is simply a scaled brownian motion?